# as an assembly worker- a dangling modifier?

Tags: dangling-modifier

Is "as an assembly worker" a dangling modifier in the following?

As an assembly worker, your duty is to check products for defects.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a reordering of *Your duty as an assembly worker...*

Compare:

> [As an artist](https://books.google.com/books?id=cYByBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYodnOvO7aAhWqdN8KHUWZBHMQ6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&f=false) his impulse is to express himself ...
>
> [As an artist](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZxOkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&dq=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf-8-Dve7aAhWIY98KHeZmAUY4FBDoAQg-MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&f=false) his aim was to reproduce ...
>
> [As an artist](https://books.google.com/books?id=NzxjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PP340&dq=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf-8-Dve7aAhWIY98KHeZmAUY4FBDoAQh-MA8#v=onepage&q=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&f=false) his latest productions were ...
>
> [as an artist](https://books.google.com/books?id=-yvqAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&dq=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwj4nXve7aAhVDnuAKHR-oB-M4KBDoAQg0MAI#v=onepage&q=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&f=false) his facility became in part paralysed by awe.
>
> [as an artist](https://books.google.com/books?id=s9l5TIzarCUC&pg=PT100&dq=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwj4nXve7aAhVDnuAKHR-oB-M4KBDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%22as%20an%20artist%20his%22&f=false) his interest in her daughter's appearance was a ...
>
> [As a singer](https://books.google.com/books?id=_NNmFiUnSmUC&pg=PA421&dq=%22as%20a%20singer%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQqtbmvu7aAhXGV98KHW_SDscQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20singer%20his%22&f=false) his seemingly lazy intonation ...
>
> [as a doctor](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mf9NAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22as%20a%20doctor%20his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3iN2gv-7aAhXjlOAKHXhJAiIQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20doctor%20his%22&f=false) his background would be more thoroughly investigated...

Comment: I think such sentences are correct, but traditional grammar says that fronted modifiers such as "as an assembly worker" must refer to the subject, but the subject is "you duty," not "you."

Comment: A prescriptivist bugbear.

Comment: I don't believe it's necessarily a reordering in the way you describe it. The use of *as* here seems ambiguous to me—although still not ungrammatical in either case. It could mean *like an assembly worker* or *since you are an assembly worker*.

Comment: (Sorry, I meant the use of *as* in the original question, with the comma.)

Comment: Well, @Apollyon, I'll agree that the OP subject is "your duty".  I can't quite agree that *you* has anything to do with it.  This duty as an artist may well be yours, but that's incidental.  "As an artist" still refers to the subject in either case.

Answer (score 0):

(I originally said the following in a series of comments, then thought I should turn it into an actual answer.)

It is not a dangling modifier. A dangling modifier confuses subject with object. That is not the case here. There is a clear subject (you) who can perform an action (checking for defects) on an object (the products).

A possible version of this, that *would* be an example of a dangling modifier is:

> Having checked for defects, the products were assembled.

That's wrong because it implies that *the products* were doing the defect checking, not *you*.

In your sentence, *as an assembly worker* is simply a subordinate clause.